# get data from one API that is dependent on another API flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello friends I am learning to build apps in Flutter. it's a single screen must display data from second api using user_id value from the first api.I have api response from server like this :

```
    {
        "code": 0,
        "message": "",
        "data": [
            {
                "userbox_id": 7,
                "user_id": 53,
                "box_id": 55,
                "status": 0,
                "created_at": "2021-04-28T11:55:12.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-28T11:55:12.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "userbox_id": 8,
                "user_id": 53,
                "box_id": 56,
                "status": 0,
                "created_at": "2021-04-29T10:29:43.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-29T10:29:43.000000Z"
            },
    "error": [],
    "status": 200
}
```

I would like to use "user_id" value to fetch data from second API response .

How i can do that ?

the first method:

```
Future<List<ActiveBox>> fetchBoxes() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = localStorage.getString('access_token');
    await checkInternet();
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    };
    var url = Uri.parse(ApiUtil.GET_ALL_BOXES);
    var response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        // print(response.statusCode);
        var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
        print(body);
        List<ActiveBox> boxes = [];
        for (var item in body['data']) {
          boxes.add(ActiveBox.fromJson(item));
        }
        print(boxes);
        inspect(boxes);
        return boxes;
```

and the second method :

```
Future<User> getUser() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = localStorage.getString('access_token');
    print(token);
    await checkInternet();
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    };
    var url = Uri.parse(ApiUtil.GET_USER);
    var response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
        User users = User.fromJson(body);
        return users;
```

how i can implement that ? any help please

Comment: after you called first api, you want to call second or for example you show some info in screen1 from first api and then in screen2 you want to show info from second api ?

Comment: it's a single screen . i would like to point on user_id value to access to all information of the second api . it's a single screen display data from second api using user_id value from the first api.

Comment: i highly recommend to you for using a stage-management like (bloc), but i think you can do this:
first you show all info in screen from first api, then when user click on user_id (or other stuff) you call second api and show coming info on a modal or something like this.

Comment: sorry not working for me